# Get a list of active printers from within PHP

Tags: php, linux, printing

I'm using PHP to get an active list of printers connected to my Xubuntu linux machine and then create an array that shows only the printers which are online. I wanted to use this array to determine programmatically, which printer can be used to print.

To accomplish this, I call from within PHP

```
lpstat -p -d
```

This gives the response:

```
printer DYMO-LabelWriter-400-Turbo-1 disabled since Fri 26 Jul 2013 10:45:50 AM UTC -
    Unable to send data to printer.
printer DYMO-LabelWriter-400-Turbo-2 is idle.  enabled since Mon 04 Nov 2013 04:30:57 AM UTC
printer Samsung-SCX-4200 is idle.  enabled since Wed 10 Jul 2013 11:30:49 AM UTC
system default destination: DYMO-LabelWriter-400-Turbo-1
```

However, this list is incorrect. At the time of running the call, none of the above printers are actually connected. Is there a way to probe, if the printer can be used at all?

EDIT:
Here's the code I use:

```
function getActivePrinters() {

    $o = shell_exec("lpstat -d -p");
    $res = explode("\n", $o);
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($res as $r) {
        $active = 0;
        if (strpos($r, "printer") !== FALSE) {
            $r = str_replace("printer ", "", $r);
            if (strpos($r, "is idle") !== FALSE)
                $active = 1;

            $r = explode(" ", $r);

            $printers[$i]['name'] = $r[0];
            $printers[$i]['active'] = $active;
            $i++;
        }
    }
    return $printers;
}
```

Comment: Is it that you're using `system('lpstat -p -d')` to get that list? If so, have you tried using `echo '<pre>', print_r(printer_list(PRINTER_ENUM_LOCAL), true), '</pre>';` and seeing what that returns?

Comment: I don't have the printer extension installed. So I get a call to undefined function error. I've added the code I'm using.

Comment: It would be easier to use regex than explode, if you need help with that regex, provide the output you get when you run that command line

Comment: What happens when you run `lpstat -p -d` from the CLI by hand, is it different from the list you get when running it through php? If so, could it be the user php is running as why you are getting different results there?

Comment: [Here's the repository of .dll extensions for PHP if you'd like to install the printer extension](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/)

Comment: @nrathaus I tried to use something that runs very fast because the servers it runs on are partly Raspberry Pi's. The output is above (response).

Comment: @quickshiftin The list is exactly the same in the console. So the command itself is the problem. My issue with extensions is that it will run on several different servers which have the extension not yet installed. I thought there was a way to just copy the PHP scripts.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Thanks. If no other solution is found, I'll try that route.

Comment: @user1288263 Sorry I couldn't have been more help here, if it's any consolation, I wasn't able to resolve it using `lpstat` either, but using the `printer_list` was correct on my centos box.

Comment: @user1288263 Then this question really has nothing to do with PHP. It's really about the behavior of `lpstat` on different systems. You might want to revise this question or open a new one to that effect for better help.

Comment: Saved me a couple of hours this morning - thanks!